# Curious trigraph sequence thing about ansi C

Tags: c, chars, trigraphs

What was is it the original reason to use **trigraph sequence** of some chars to become other chars in ansi C like:

```
??=define arraycheck(a, b) a??(b??) ??!??! b??(a??)
```

becomes

```
#define arraycheck(a, b) a[b] || b[a]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer: keyboards/character encodings that didn't include such graphs.

From wikipedia:

> The basic character set of the C programming language is a superset of the ASCII character set that includes nine characters which lie outside the ISO 646 invariant character set. This can pose a problem for writing source code when the keyboard being used does not support any of these nine characters. The ANSI C committee invented trigraphs as a way of entering source code using keyboards that support any version of the ISO 646 character set.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Digraphs_and_trigraphs

Answer (score 1):

Some old keyboards didn't have specific characters on them, so the language worked around it by letting you use trigraphs instead.

Comment: mmm, interesting, so it was back in 1983? or something?

Comment: It's not just that they keyboards might not have the characters on them; the *character sets* themselves might have no way to encode those characters. For example, EBCDIC doesn't have `{` and `}` I believe.